# how to parse eclipse for POSTGRESQL libpq

Tags: c++, postgresql, libpqxx

I would like to compile this [program](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_c_cpp.htm) with Eclipse in a manner equivalent to this:

```
g++ test.cpp -lpqxx -lpq
```

but I can't find how to set it. I read the forum and did not find any satisfactory answer.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Do you get an error of compilation or you can't find the location to add compiler arguments?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that the Eclipse project has its own general purpose mailing list, or a web forum for its users. I'm curious why you think you're more likely to get help with Eclipse here, then on Eclipse's own user mailing lists, or web forums?

Comment: Thank you  Some progammer  My error : makefile:45 : la recette pour la cible « connection2 » a échouée
make: *** [connection2] Erreur 1